Assessing significant differences between nls models in R
I have a dataset where I modeled y based on x using nls() with an exponential function in R. I fitted a combined model where two parameters per treatment where estimated and a simple model, where for both treatments combined, two parameters were estimated. The code was the following. Then I used anova() to see if estimating two separate estimates per treatment significantly improves the model. Is this statistically correct? Additionally, I would like to see which treatment was more sensitive towards a change in x. How can I do this?
y and x are both continuous, numeric variables. y ranges from 0 to 1 and is a negative value.
    # Fit a single nls model that accounts for size as a factor
try(
  nls_mod_combined <- nls(
    y ~ (a * exp(b * x)) * (treatment == "hot") + 
      (c * exp(d * x)) * (treatment == "cold"), 
    start = list(a = 0.5, b = 0.5, c = 0.5, d = 0.5), 
    data = subset_combined
  )
)

try(
  nls_mod_simple <- nls(
    y ~ a * exp(b * x), 
    start = list(a = 0.5, b = 0.5), 
    data = subset_combined
  )
)
anova_result <- anova(nls_mod_simple, nls_mod_combined)


The models need to be nested which they are if treatment can only be hot or cold.  Note that using algorithm = "plinear" and modifying the formulas appropriately would eliminate the need for a starting value for the linear parameters (a and c in the first model and for a in the second model).  Loo for plinear examples on SO.

"Additionally, I would like to see which treatment was more sensitive towards a change in x." This means that b and d would need to differ between treatments. You can use nlme::gnls. It allows specifying linear models for parameters of the non-linear model (see argument params).
